# How to create a Python executable using Docker

Tags: python, docker

I have a running python executable EIA.py which extracts information from EIA.gov website and downloads necessary information into an excel file on my laptop's C:/Python Folder. However, when I convert this file into image and run using docker run command for image it gives me following error.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Python/Sid.xls'

I am not adding any file but Python should rather create an excel file with contents extracted from website.

## Following is my code from Dockerfile

```
 FROM python
 VOLUME ["C:/Sid"]
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY . /app
 RUN pip install EIA-python
 RUN pip install requests
 RUN pip install pandas
 RUN pip install xlwt
 RUN python /app/EIA.py
```

## Following is my python code

```
 import eia
 import pandas as pd

 api_key = "mykey"
 api = eia.API(api_key)

 series_storage = api.data_by_series(series='NG.NW2_EPG0_SWO_R48_BCF.W')
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(series_storage)
 df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
 df1.columns = ['Date', 'Value']
 df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'].str[:-3], format='%Y %m%d')
 df1.to_excel("C:/Python/Sid.xls")
```

Answer (score 3):

Docker containers do not have persistent storage. To save a file locally from a container, you can either bind a folder mount or create a docker volume. Docker volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data as they are completely managed within Docker CLI itself. Check out [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for more info.

Comment: I am sorry but your instructions are not working as intended.